# Google cloud storage webui shows incorrect `created time`

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Google cloud storage webui shows incorrect `created time`, "Jan 1, 1970, 1:00:00 AM" even though the folder is newly created.

Sceenshot1: [image: Incorrect "created time"]

It has correct `created time` in the detailed info.

Screenshot2: [image: Correct "created time" in the detailed info]

Is there a way to show the correct `created time` on the list view?

Comment: The issue is known and has been reported to Google. Another GUI issues has been spotted. We are waiting for a fix or rollback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem so this is an issue related to the console. I found this [public Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/162352630) that mentions it.

The workaround is  use the command **gsutil ls -lah -r gs://mybucket** in order to get more information about the objects inside the bucket